# hortensia and brown leaves

Tags: hydrangea

I have an hortensia which is getting more and more brown leaves (see pictures)

[image]
[image]

Ground seems OK (not dry). Any idea on a possible cause?

**Edit**

I am using tap water as I did for years, the same I use for all the other plants.

This are the moisture level measured with Parrot Flower Power (I have no previous values due to a strange bug):

[image]

The vase has some gravel on the bottom and a hole at the bottom.

I added some fertiliser one week ago (a specific product for hortensiae from Gesal: 7% Nitrogen, 3% Phosphorus pentoxide, 5% Potassium oxide, 0,01% B; 0,002% Cu*; 0,05% Fe*; 0,02% Mn*; 0,001% Mo; 0,002% Zn*)

The leaves began to turn brown a couple of weeks ago but in the last few days it seems that it is accelerating.

Comment: I think it has too much water in the roots.

Comment: Please send close ups, what is your watering schedule and obviously you are using tap water.  My first reaction is tap water.  How long ago did this start happening?  What was happening at that time?  What fertilizer are you using and when was the last 'application'?  What soil are you using?  Is there a hole in the bottom?  Do you allow the water to sit in the 'saucer'?  Did you put rocks/gravel/pebbles at the bottom of that pot beneath the soil?  Too much water would be obvious from all of the foliage, not from just completely dead, dry leaves throughout.  Plenty of healthy foliage.

Comment: Hi Matteo! @stormy has asked some important questions. When you add the pictures, could you also [edit] the answers right into your question? It makes it easier for people to see all the information in one place. Also,  comments don't always last forever. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try flushing with plenty of water to reduce the minerals load in the vase and let the water % drop to 5% before watering.

**Don't** water again until you poke your finger into the soil and feel that the soil is **almost** dry.

Also, the moisture level detector is not recommended. Visual, finger poke and weight of the vase are more reliable to determine whether the plant needs watering :)